# C++ Input to .txt

Tags: c++, input

I've been working on a notebook program for a few days and have ran into a problem that I can't seem to figure out. The code bellow runs just fine, but the final outcome has me scratching my head.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int main ()
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
    std::string note;
    int day = ltm->tm_mday;
    int month = 1 + ltm->tm_mon;
    int year = 1900 + ltm->tm_year;
    std::string d = std::to_string(day);
    std::string m = std::to_string(month);
    std::string y = std::to_string(year);
    std::string text;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);

    if(text.find("take ") != std::string::npos && 
       text.find("note ") != std::string::npos)
    {
        {
            std::ofstream myfile ("C:\\Users\\Filepath\\" + m + d + y + ".txt");
            if (myfile.is_open())
                {
                    std::cin >> note;
                    myfile << note << "\n";
                }
            else 
                {
                    std::cout << "Could not create note. Write it down." << endl;
                }
        }
    }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

If I were to type into the command prompt "Give invite to Sander Cohen."

When I open the text file, all that is in it is, "Give"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `std::cin >> note; myfile << note << "\n";` is run only once. That's why you see only the first word.

Comment: `cin>>note` returns only the first word (no space or punctation). Use `getline`to read a line

Comment: I applied this after the filepath if-statement myfile << std::getline(std::cin, note) << "\n"; No matter what I wrote, inside the command prompt after running it, inside the .txt, was **58D5C288**. Any ideas?

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, note)` will write the content of `cin` to `note`, so you should use it like this: `std::getline(std::cin, note); myfile << note;`. 58D5C288 is an address of `getline` function in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one problem, `cin` only inputs the first word, not the whole line. This is a very easy fix, here is your new code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int main ()
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
    std::string note;
    int day = ltm->tm_mday;
    int month = 1 + ltm->tm_mon;
    int year = 1900 + ltm->tm_year;
    std::string d = std::to_string(day);
    std::string m = std::to_string(month);
    std::string y = std::to_string(year);
    std::string text;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);

    if(text.find("take ") != std::string::npos &&
       text.find("note ") != std::string::npos)
    {
        {
            std::ofstream myfile ("C:\\Users\\Filepath\\" + m + d + y + ".txt");
            if (myfile.is_open())
            {
                std::getline(std::cin, note); // getline
                myfile << note << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Could not create note. Write it down." << std::endl; // make sure you have std:: befor endl
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

*Good luck with your notebook program!*